# Join method not iterating over entire array

Tags: ruby, arrays

So I'm trying to change the output of my array from:

```
------
|*...|
------
|..*.|
------
|....|
------
```

to

```
---------
|*|.|.|.|
---------
|.|.|*|.|
---------
|.|.|.|.|
---------
```

Below is the code sample

```
def load_board(file)
  gameboard = File.readlines(file)[1..-1]
  gameboard.map! do |line|
    line.split.map(&:to_s)
  end

  $globalboard = gameboard
end


def pp_board(board)
  puts Array.new(board[0].size*2+1, '-').join('')
  board.each do |row|
    puts "|" + row.join('|') + "|"
    puts Array.new(row.size*2+1, '-').join('')
  end
end


load_board('mines.txt')
pp_board($globalboard)
```

For some reason it appears that the row.join('|') method isn't doing anything, is there a reason for this?

The content of the mines.txt file is

```
4 3
*...
..*.
....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't doing anything"? - do you get the || printed for each row but nothing in between? What's in mines.txt?

Comment: Yes, I get a | at the end and beginning of each row, nothing in between each character of the row.

mines.txt is 
    `4 3`

    `*...`

    `..*.`

    `....`

Comment: Can you post the content of the file, plase? In the question, as a formatted block of code, not here in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map!`:

```
def load_board(file)
    gameboard = File.readlines(file)[1..-1]
    gameboard.map! do |line|
        line.split.map(&:to_s)
    end
    $globalboard = gameboard
end
```

Simple `map` without `!` does not affect `gameboard` array and creates a new one. `map!` affects the original array `gameboard`. That's why `gameboard` didn't contain splitted lines.

---

> For some reason it appears that the row.join('|') method isn't doing anything, is there a reason for this?

`line.split` splits a line `"*..."` as `["*..."]`. But I think you want it to split by every character. So you need `line.split("")`. This will produce `["*", ".", ".", "."]`.

Also `.map(&:to_s)` is redundant because splitted array in `line.split("")` will always contain strings.

Comment: So now the code in the question is including this answer, and the question has changed. Now it looks like this answer doesn't make much sense anymore.

Comment: Indeed, phts helped me out with the initial problem and asked me to update the top post with the new issue.

Comment: *For some reason it appears that the row.join('|') method isn't doing anything* - checkout the updated answer